# Animating css property in Vue.js watch, performance issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm animating background position of an image in a watcher

HTML

```
<div :class="$style.holder">
        <div :class="$style.inner" :style="{'background-position-x': pos + '%'}"></div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
this.$store.watch(state => state.frameRate.lastTime, now => {
            this.pos += (now - lastTime) * (window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight);
            lastTime = now;
        });
```

So my image moves pretty much constantly.

The problem is sometimes image moves jumpy, especially on mobile, sometimes at the beginning of animation, sometimes during it.

And I wonder how to fix this issue. Is it a case were `requestAnimationFrame` can help?

Comment: Seems like an ideal use case for basic CSS transitions

Comment: @StephenThomas I don't know, the animation itself is smooth, the problem is the performance